# How to get entered text from a textbox having no value attribute in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My element looks like this:

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderPopUp$ReviewName" 
       type="text" maxlength="255" id="PlaceHolderPopUp_ReviewName" 
       class="giInput_two inputHeight_two" 
       style="height:20px;width:100%;">
```

Retrieving code:

```
String value=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='PlaceHolderPopUp_ReviewName']")).getText().trim();
```

I want to enter some text in it and retrieve the text before saving. I used `getText()` method but it is not retrieving any text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If target element is `input` element, you should try as below :-

```
WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='PlaceHolderPopUp_ReviewName']"));
String value = el.getAttribute("value");
```

**Note** :- `input` element always contains entered text in their attribute property `value`. It does matter that their attribute `value` present or not.
Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Please don't use XPath when a simple `By.id()` will work. There's absolutely no reason to do so. This code will work and is faster than using XPath: `String value = driver.findElement(By.id("PlaceHolderPopUp_ReviewName")).getAttribute("value");`

Comment: @JeffC  you are absolutely right but this is not OP's  questions  that which is faster than `xpath`...he just wants to know how to get value from `input` in his code....

Comment: @JeffC you could suggest him with your suggestions but this is not a reason for down vote...

Comment: @JeffC could please tell me how much faster by using `id` in this case???

Comment: His question didn't require XPath. If you are going to provide an answer, it should be the best answer possible. There's no reason to use XPath in this case. By id is several times faster than XPath. XPath is the slowest find method there is.

Comment: @JeffC so you can provide best answer by your suggestion...you have rights to provide best to bestest answer...but my answer has no reason for downvote.. i gave the answer which OP want...

Comment: @JeffC its just simpl `XPath` not much more complex...and did you test this case By `id` and by `XPath` and then telling by using `id` is faster than `xpath` or its just your thought...??

Comment: I have tested id (and other location methods) vs XPath many times and it's always faster. No, I did not test it in this specific case because I can't. If you do some googling and read, you will find that XPath is the slowest. If you look at the Selenium documentation, it even says that id, etc. should be preferred over XPath. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements

Comment: @JeffC yeah I know it very well....but this is not OP's question...if OP asks for that which is best way to locate an element regarding speed I defently apriciate your suggestion...anyway thank you...:)

Comment: OP asked for how to find an element. You provided code that used an XPath that consisted only of an ID. By.id() should have been preferred. I've given you reasons, examples, and links supporting this decision. End of story. The performance issue is just another reason to avoid XPath when possible.

Comment: @JeffC No, OP asked for how to get value from input...and OP already got the element by possible way...he just want to get value...

Comment: @JeffC have a look http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.47.1/org/openqa/selenium/By.java#By.ById...here selenium alternatively uses `Xpath` with id to find en element...

Answer (score 1):

You can take the string which you are entering in a variable and use the same in your script. For example:

```
String Text ="Name"
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='PlaceHolderPopUp_ReviewName']")).sendkeys(Text);
```

So you can use the Text variable wherever you want instead of reading it from text box.

If you really want to read you can try `getAttribute("Value")` instead of `getText()`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input _ngcontent-c16="" class="form-control input-sm ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" formcontrolname="usrPwd" id="usrPwd" maxlength="15" name="usrPwd" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

If there is no "Value" attribute is present then how retrive the text from "Password" text box

My code is given below for refrence.

```
WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.id("usrPwd"));
Password.sendKeys("Future1234");
String Text = driver.findElement(By.id("usrPwd")).getAttribute("Value");
System.out.println(Text);
```